# solaris + dladm + what is unknown state and how to bring it to up?

Tags: networking, solaris

I installed Solaris 10 on my netra machine

from dladm show-dev I can see which interface are down or up

all interfaces are connected to the Cisco switch , and all leds are light's on all LAN cards

but I not understand why all interfaces except e1000g0 are in unknown ?

Please advice how to bring the unknown interfaces to up ?

```
  # dladm show-dev
  e1000g0         link: up        speed: 1000  Mbps       duplex: full
  e1000g1         link: unknown   speed: 0     Mbps       duplex: unknown
  e1000g2         link: unknown   speed: 0     Mbps       duplex: unknown
  e1000g3         link: unknown   speed: 0     Mbps       duplex: unknown
  nxge0           link: unknown   speed: 0     Mbps       duplex: unknown
  nxge1           link: unknown   speed: 0     Mbps       duplex: unknown
  nxge2           link: unknown   speed: 0     Mbps       duplex: unknown
  nxge3           link: unknown   speed: 0     Mbps       duplex: unknown
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link status is set to 'unknown' because the interfaces have never been "plumbed" via ifconfig, yet. This is what I saw on my test machine:

```
# dladm show-dev
bge0            link: up        speed: 1000  Mbps       duplex: full
bge1            link: up        speed: 1000  Mbps       duplex: full
bge2            link: unknown   speed: 0     Mbps       duplex: unknown
bge3            link: unknown   speed: 0     Mbps       duplex: unknown
# ifconfig bge2 plumb
# dladm show-dev
bge0            link: up        speed: 1000  Mbps       duplex: full
bge1            link: up        speed: 1000  Mbps       duplex: full
bge2            link: down      speed: 0     Mbps       duplex: unknown
bge3            link: unknown   speed: 0     Mbps       duplex: unknown
```

After plumbing the link state went from 'unknown' to 'down' (because the interface is not connected). Speed and duplex will show up once the interfaces are "upped" by ifconfig and they are indeed connected to a switch.